# as3: How to organize classes

Tags: actionscript-3, oop

It's a bit basic question. But, I fail to understand how to solve it. I have an application which has several enteties. E.g. pike <-- fish --> shark. Where fish is a base class.

I am doing some kind of lake, so all my instances of fish class can move only within some boarders. Even more, they all are randomly created on one of the edges of the lake and swim to another depending on the edge they are located at. Here is how it looks for a base class:

```
public class Fish extends FlxSprite
{

    [Embed(source="./resources/Elipse.png")]
    public var image:Class;

    // Variable which stores the direction of item movement (false - Move right)
    // (true - Move Left)
    private var movement:Boolean;

    public function Fish(x:int, y:int)
    {
        super(x, y, image);

        // Move right
        if ( x < 5 )
        {
            movement = false;
        }
        else
        {
            movement = true;
        }
    }



    public override function update():void
    {
        if( movement )
        {
            this.velocity.x -= 3;
        }

        else
        {
            this.velocity.x += 3;
        }

        super.update();
 }
```

Now I want to extend this model to add some extra behaviour to the fish class. E.g. I want to make a shark. To do so I need to:

1) Replace the image of abstract fish with an image of shark

2) Change the behaviour a bit (shark still needs to know about direction but maybe use another approach to velocities)

3) Define size property (e.g. based on size the shark would be stronger or weaker)

The question is:

How do I define a shark... As a subclass of Fish? Or it's better to subclass it from Sprite?

I thought that subclassing from Fish would be more natural way, but in this case, I do not understand how to override the visual presentation of the Fish (e.g. image), as it's impossible to override a variable.

From the other hand if I will use FlxSprite as a base class, it would be easy to redefine the presentation, but in the case I would not be able to reuse the movement code (e.g. so fish knows in which direction to swim)...

I understand that the question is a bit hard to understand. Happy to re-define it in case of any questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't override a variable (it wouldn't make any sense), but you can set its value in the constructor.

in `Fish`:

```
public var image:Class;
```

in `Shark`:

```
[Embed(source="./resources/shark.png")]
private const _sharkImage:Class;

public function Shark(x:int, y:int)
{
  image = _sharkImage;
  super(x, y);
}
```

---

You could also use a getter.

In `Fish`:

```
[Embed(source="./resources/Elipse.png")]
public var _image:Class;

public function get image():Class
{
  return _image;
}
```

and then in `Shark`:

```
[Embed(source="./resources/shark.png")]
private const _sharkImage:Class;

override public function get image():Class
{
  return _sharkImage;
}
```

I think overriding getters and setters is a good option for you. You could then change the behavioral velocity/size for each species.

Comment: Kodiak is right. I would like to add, that the underlying idea is, that in Olegs example, the image field represents a very concrete attribute (the visual representation of a fish). It is misplaced in that class. If you think of it, the abstract concept of a fish cannot have a concrete representation, because how can a fish possibly look like, if you don't know, what concrete fish it is. The only thing you can say is, that a fish has a visual representation in general. In any concrete subclass then, like Kodiak suggests, you can specify that concrete representation.

Comment: Good point! I will move the presentation out of the abstract class

Comment: Small question here. If I would need to add 5 different sizes of the same shark (e.g. each of them has different size of the image) how would I do it? It's a bit strange to create 5 subclasses in this case?

Comment: If we consider your size as an Array of two values, you could define the different sizes of your shark as static constant of the Shark class and add the size as a parameter of the shark's constructor: new Shark(0, 0, Shark.SIZE_SMALL) where 0 and 0 are x and y and SIZE_SMALL one of the possible values for a shark's size.

Comment: And depending on the size I would need to embed different image in Constructor? Or initialize the class in a different way. What do I do in case I need to change behaviour of a big shark (so it's more agressive?) what would be a general approach there

Comment: If too many parameters change from one type of shark to another, it becomes a good idea to create a child class. You could also do something inspired by the factory design pattern: create a method Fish.create(type:String):Fish which returns a Fish of the specific type declared by the parameter. Fish.create("smallShark") for example would return a Shark object with every variable parameter correctly set by this method.